# Is compressed air effective to clean a 2018 MacBook Pro keyboard which displays repeated keypresses?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

My 2018, 15" MacBook Pro is starting to display the dreaded keyboard defects. Specifically, the <kbd>A</kbd> key started to register double keypresses. Initially this was very infrequent, but it appears to be getting worse. I would estimate that, in the last few minutes, about 5-10% of the time, a repeat keypress is happening.

Although I could take the computer to an authorized repair shop as it's still under warranty (and I bought AppleCare for it), I know the turnaround time is fairly long, and this is the only computer I can realistically use without immensely disrupting my workflow. Also, there is no Apple Store within 500 Km of my location. Therefore, I set out to look for DIY fixes.

I found [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205662) support document on Apple's site recommending the use of compressed air as a possible fix to the issue. I have an oil-free air compressor that I could use to apply compressed air to the keyboard.

However, I'm somewhat afraid of doing this. Although this is an Apple recommended procedure, I can't help but think this is aggressive procedure applied to a very delicate mechanism. In particular, I'm afraid my compressed air source may have a small rate of dust contamination which may actually worsen the problem. Has anyone actually used this procedure on a 2018 MacBook Pro keyboard, with the new [silicone membrane](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/07/19/ifixit-2018-macbook-pro-keyboard-dust-exposure/), to see whether this recommendation is actually effective? I intend to postpone doing this until I see a success report.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Butterfly' keyboard Apple uses is known to be faulty and many users experience problems with it. A quick google search for 'Butterfly Keyboard Problems' will show you the scale of this issue. The solution you found may work, but I would strongly suggest taking it back to Apple, since its still under warranty it should be free and it will likely prolong the lifespan of your Macbook.